# If new file in FTP-Server run program

Tags: python, for-loop, if-statement, ftp, monitor

is there a simple way to monitor a ftp Server all the time, and run your Programm with the newest file in the folder ?

Comment: Lookup `inotify`; voting to close as off topic.

Comment: Monitor where? On the server-side or on client-side?

Comment: Monitor on the server side.

Comment: And if there is a new file uploaded, run the program for it